# String Manipulating and slicing from a list

Tags: string, list, python-3.x

```
import os

a = ['docs-assets', 'ico', 'favicon.png']
for item in range(len(a)):
    z = os.path.join("sample",a[item])
print(z)
```

Results:

```
sample\docs-assets
sample\ico
sample\favicon.png
```

Can you tell me how i can join each item in the "a" list using os.path.join() so that the result would be:

```
sample\docs-assets\ico\favicon.png
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[Like so:](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#unpacking-argument-lists)

```
os.path.join('sample', *a)
```

Comment: Can you please explain '*a', what does * do? Your code works.

Comment: It's explained in the link.

Comment: @user3454234: `f(0, *[1,2,3])` calls `f(0,1,2,3)`

Answer (score 0):

You can do it as:

```
s = 'sample\\'+'\\'.join(a)

>>> print s
sample\docs-assets\ico\favicon.png
```

### DEMO

Comment: There is no way to get the desired result using os.path.join()?